# Cambiar orden de datos MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta que me trae los datos de forma ordenada:

```
$table = $db->query("SELECT * FROM courier_track WHERE t_id='".Filter::$id."'");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que se invierta el orden.

Leí que con `ORDER BY ASC` se logra pero no me invierte la información, así lo intente.

```
$table = $db->query("SELECT * FROM courier_track WHERE t_id='".Filter::$id."' ORDER BY id ASC");
```

¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Debería ser **ORDER BY id DESC**

Comment: ese era muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay básicamente dos tipos de orden:

- **Ascendente**: ordena de menor a mayor. Es el orden por defecto, cuando no pones ningún tipo de orden se asume este, pero que se puede indicar también de forma explícita con la palabra `ASC`
- **Descendente**: ordena de mayor a menor. Hay que indicarlo de forma explícita mediante la palabra `DESC`.

Quisiera aportar aquí una traducción del Manual de Referencia sobre la forma de ordenar filas mediante `ORDER BY`, que serviría para aclarar los conceptos y para ampliar horizontes, sabiendo que se pueden ordenar los resultados por varias columnas por ejemplo y que ese orden puede combinarse entre `ASC` y `DESC` por columnas. También está el caso de  `BINARY` que conviene conocer.

> **[3.3.4.4 Ordenar filas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)**
>
> ... A menudo es más fácil examinar el resultado de la consulta cuando
>   las filas se ordenan de alguna manera significativa. Para ordenar un
>   resultado, use una cláusula `ORDER BY`.
>
> Aquí hay cumpleaños de animales, ordenados por fecha (nótese que al no
>   poner nada se asume un orden ascendente por defecto):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT name, birth FROM pet ORDER BY birth;
> +----------+------------+
> | name     | birth      |
> +----------+------------+
> | Buffy    | 1989-05-13 |
> | Bowser   | 1989-08-31 |
> | Fang     | 1990-08-27 |
> | Fluffy   | 1993-02-04 |
> | Claws    | 1994-03-17 |
> | Slim     | 1996-04-29 |
> | Whistler | 1997-12-09 |
> | Chirpy   | 1998-09-11 |
> | Puffball | 1999-03-30 |
> +----------+------------+
> ```
>
> En las columnas de tipo de caracteres (cadenas), el orden, -como todas
>   las demás operaciones de comparación-, se realiza normalmente sin
>   distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Esto significa que el orden
>   es el mismo para las columnas que son idénticas, aunque estén en
>   mayúsculas o minúsculas. Puede forzar una ordenación entre mayúsculas
>   y minúsculas para una columna utilizando `BINARY` de la siguiente
>   manera:
>
> ```
> ORDER BY BINARY col_name
> ```
>
> El orden predeterminado es ascendente, que ordena los valores
>   partiendo del más pequeño. Para ordenar en orden inverso
>   (descendente), agregue la palabra clave `DESC` al nombre de la columna
>   por la que está ordenando:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT name, birth FROM pet ORDER BY birth DESC;
> +----------+------------+
> | name     | birth      |
> +----------+------------+
> | Puffball | 1999-03-30 |
> | Chirpy   | 1998-09-11 |
> | Whistler | 1997-12-09 |
> | Slim     | 1996-04-29 |
> | Claws    | 1994-03-17 |
> | Fluffy   | 1993-02-04 |
> | Fang     | 1990-08-27 |
> | Bowser   | 1989-08-31 |
> | Buffy    | 1989-05-13 |
> +----------+------------+
> ```
>
> Puede ordenar por varias columnas, y puede ordenar diferentes columnas
>   en diferentes tipos de orden (ascendente o descedente). Por ejemplo,
>   para ordenar por tipo de animal en orden ascendente, luego por fecha
>   de nacimiento dentro del tipo de animal en orden descendente (primero
>   los animales más jóvenes), utilice la siguiente consulta:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT name, species, birth FROM pet
>        ORDER BY species, birth DESC;
> +----------+---------+------------+
> | name     | species | birth      |
> +----------+---------+------------+
> | Chirpy   | bird    | 1998-09-11 |
> | Whistler | bird    | 1997-12-09 |
> | Claws    | cat     | 1994-03-17 |
> | Fluffy   | cat     | 1993-02-04 |
> | Fang     | dog     | 1990-08-27 |
> | Bowser   | dog     | 1989-08-31 |
> | Buffy    | dog     | 1989-05-13 |
> | Puffball | hamster | 1999-03-30 |
> | Slim     | snake   | 1996-04-29 |
> +----------+---------+------------+
> ```
>
> La palabra clave `DESC` se aplica solo al nombre de columna
>   inmediatamente anterior (`birth`); no afecta el orden de clasificación
>   de la columna `species`.

Con esto queda explicado todo lo relativo a ordenar filas en MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

> ASC es de Ascendiente, osea que va subiendo, de menor a mayor. En el caso de la respuesta que estas recibiento ya esta ordenada de esa manera, asi que si no pones nada y si pones `ORDER BY id ASC` es exactamente igual.

```
$table = $db->query("SELECT * FROM courier_track WHERE t_id='".Filter::$id."' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Eso deberia devolverte la consulta invertida, que es el orden que la necesitas.